# new Date() not working not working inside chrome

Tags: javascript, date, clock

```js
var d = new Date();
var h = d.getHour();
var m = d.getMinute();
var s = d.getSecond();

if (h == 12) {
  alert(h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " PM");
} else {
  alert(h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " AM");
}
```

What should i do?
Should i change the d.getMinute() to d.getMin()?

Thank you all

Comment: Please read the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#JavaScript_Date_instances . If the browser tells you something like "`undefined` is not a function" then you are trying to access something that doesn't exist. The documentation will tell you what exists, no need to guess.

Comment: Thank you @FelixKling !

Answer (score 1):

The methods are all supposed to be pluralized:

```
var d = new Date();    
var h = d.getHours();
var m = d.getMinutes();    
var s = d.getSeconds();    
if(h == 12) {
    alert(h+":"+m+":"+s+" PM");
} else {
    alert(h+":"+m+":"+s+" AM");
}
```

For more more information about the Date methods: [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp)

Comment: No problem! Additionally there are many options for formatting a date in JavaScript discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date